# navigator.geolocation coords, used as params in the api url, load after the weatherAPI has already been called

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, fetch-api, use-effect, query-string

I am using `navigator.geolocation` to get the latitude and longitude of the user. I am then using latitude and longitude as query params to fetch the WeatherAPI so that my website will show the user the weather in his exact town.

The problem is, I can see from the console log that the `fetch()` function (which I have stored inside `useEffect()` runs before the `navigator.geolocation`, resulting in the API fetching me a location with coordinates 0, 0.

I have tried using the fetch inside the geolocation function, as well as async/await, but since it's already inside useEffect, it won't work.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

```
const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(0)
const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(0)
const [location, setLocation] = useState([])
    
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) => {
    setLatitude(position.coords.latitude)
    setLongitude(position.coords.longitude)
})
    
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=db698b5e650a441fae6190451221401&q=${latitude},${longitude}&days=1&aqi=yes&alerts=yes`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { 
            const locationData = data;
            setLocation(locationData);
        });
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState([])   
    
useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) => {
            fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=db698b5e650a441fae6190451221401&q=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&days=1&aqi=yes&alerts=yes`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => { 
                const locationData = data;
                setLocation(locationData);
            });
        })           
}, [])
```